# Why delete query does not work in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a comment system & I created a page that admins can be able to delete comments. I have coded everything & it seems to be right but I don't know why it's not working at all...

Here's the code to the admins page:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Admins Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php 
    function getCM(){
        global $con;
        $get_comment = "select * from product_comments where type='0'";
        $run_comment = mysqli_query($con, $get_comment);
        while($row_comment = mysqli_fetch_array($run_comment)){
            $cmid = $row_comment["id"];
            $cmcode = $row_comment["productcode"];
            $cmemail = $row_comment["email"];
            $cmname= $row_comment["name"];
            $cmcomment = $row_comment["comment"];
            $cmdate = $row_comment["modified_date"];
            $cmtime = $row_comment["modified_time"];
            $cmtype = $row_comment["type"];

            echo "
                <div class='container'>
                  <div id='table' class='table-editable'>
                    <span class='table-add glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>
                    <table class='table'>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Comment ID #$cmid</th>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td contenteditable='true'>$cmcomment</td>
                        <td>
                          <span class='table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <a href='delete.php?id=$cmid'>Delete</a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>

                </div>
            ";
        }
    }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's the code to delete.php page:

```
 <?php 
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["manager"])) {
    header("location: admin_login.php"); 
    exit();
}
require '../php_includes/init/db_conx.php'; 
require '../functions/func.php'; 

    if (isset($_GET['cmid'])){
        $comment_id = $_GET['cmid'];
        mysqli_query("DELETE FROM product_comments WHERE id='$comment_id'") or die(mysql_error());
        echo "<script>alert('Comment has been deleted!')</script>";
        header("Location: product_comments.php");
    }
?>
```

Please if you know what's my problem please let me know that...

Comment: What is happening when you try to delete a comment?

Comment: For errors, fix die(mysql_error()) to die(mysqli_error()), what happens when you execute the script?

Comment: nothing happened ,just a blank page

Comment: What is the url of the blank page?

Comment: You are missing `$con` in `mysqli_query("DELETE FROM product_comments...`. It should be `mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM product_comments...`

Comment: @WilliamMadede `mysqli_error` requires the link -> `mysqli_error($con)`  not `mysqli_error()`

Comment: Don't put user input straight in to your queries. Always escape your data or preferably use prepared statements. Your code is open to SQL Injections.

Comment: http://localhost/root/admin_area/delete.php?id=2 for example

Comment: so how does `id=2` turn into `$_GET['cmid']`? `id`!=`cmid`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I keep forgetting about the *Magic* setting  - `ini_set('Magic', On);`. It would solve many of my codigng mistakes. :)

Comment: @Sean Lordie, I love it when things are that simple ;-) seems I have some competition below.

Comment: @Pouya ok, where are we with this question? I posted something below and made a few edits. So, check that out and read it in its entirety. There isn't much else I can say or do to further improve my answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things wrong here.

You didn't connect to your query `mysqli_query("DELETE...`

That function requires a database connection parameter be passed.

- Consult: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Then `mysql_error()` that `mysql_` function does not mix with anything other than its own API, use `mysqli_error($con)`, assuming a successful connection with `mysqli_` and `$con` as its variable.

- Consult: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

On the PHP side:

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

should there be errors elsewhere in your code.

which there is, in this part of your code:

```
    echo "<script>alert('Comment has been deleted!')</script>";
    header("Location: product_comments.php");
```

You are outputting before header, and need to remove the echo and adding `exit;` for the header.

Consult: [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Then this:

```
<a href='delete.php?id=$cmid'>Delete</a>
```

You are using `?id` and referencing the `$_GET['cmid']` array.

That bit ^ about the "id" is called *"Teach a person HOW to fish"*.

---

**Footnotes:**

- I have no idea where and how you are calling the `getCM()` function.

Answer (score 0):

the error you have is

```
$comment_id = $_GET['cmid'];
```

change it to this

```
  $comment_id = $_GET['id'];
```

toexplain whz

```
<a href='delete.php?id=$cmid'>Delete</a>
```

U called the cmid not id. hence u need to get id